# How Javascript's split function interprets the following regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone explain why "script" is part of the output array and how this regex is interpreted in the split function?

```js
console.log(
  "is javascript my favorite language?".split(/JAVA(Script)/i)
);
```

outputs

```
["is ", "script", " my favorite language?"]
```

Comment: I think it should be ["is ", "script", " my favorite language?"]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [MDN's docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description) say:

> If `separator` is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time `separator` is matched, the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array.

`java` is matched, but not captured, whereas `script` *is* captured in a group, so it's included in the resulting array.

Any captured groups will be included, as you can see:

```js
console.log(
  "is javascript my favorite language?".split(/JAVA(Script)( )(my)/i)
)
```